# 2N2222A as Transistor replacement

Tags: transistors

I am working on a tape sense circuit (light bulb - LDR pair) that feeds the RTL (late 60's, Apollo era logic) show at the Bottom of the pic.  This is 4V logic (4.34V).  Q11 (circled) was found bad, and replaced with 2N2222A, my "go to" NPN, and a few weeks later, it is now dead.  BE and BC are open.  The original Q11 is listed as "Sprague TZ-81", but I cannot find anything on this part #.  It does say "select for BVceo 35 volts", if that means anything.  I don't see any potential in this circuit to exceed the 2N2222A's ratings, does anyone have a clue as to how it got destroyed, or why it is not a good replacement candidate?  Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: I had no problem finding [sources for TZ81 transistors](https://pentod.com/product/4720/transistor-tz81-npn-0-5a-30v-30mhz-0-36w.html.en?CurrencyID=2). (Omit "Sprague" from the search). It was apparently used in a lot of audio equipment.  One online forum post came up in the search, [suggesting 2N3904 might be a better choice](https://groupdiy.com/threads/tz81-transistor.8537/post-101888) than 2N2222.

Comment: Wow, impressive.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

That's a pretty simple switching circuit, just about any general purpose NPN should work. With a 4 V supply and the resistances shown I don't see how it could burn out the transistor unless the power supply was getting some transients on it or some other component such as one of the resistors was shorting out. The base current should be limited to a little over 3 mA and the collector current 1 mA, nowhere near a 2N2222A's ratings.

I would guess that unless your 2N2222A was faulty to begin with whatever killed it is the same thing that killed the original transistor. I would look at the 4 V power supply for voltage spikes, check the resistors and look for any possible short circuits, especially to the LDR. The only other thing would be the inverter IC, if it was to somehow get a short between it's supply and the input pin, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Spot on, this is my consensus.  Gonna try again, maybe monitor for transients.  If it happens again, there is something else failing.  Thank you.

Comment: Gonna double down on part of this -- if it's just killed its second transistor then it's either malfunctioning or psychotic.  Either way you need to cure the underlying problem.